# How to populate image thumbnails (image grid) on my web page using JSP

Tags: ajax, database, image, jsp, jquery

I wants to populate image thumbnails (image grid) on my web page using JSP. Please suggest the  best way. Also please suggest what should I store in the DB, image in binary format or path of the image in text format  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer would be `It depends on your project requirements`

I would like to write my experience, if the images had to be prevented from un-authorized access then database would be a good option, but ASAIK I haven't developed any such application in past 3 years. I would just prefer putting up the images in a folder and then have their name in DB for reference purposes.

I just thing database has more important information to store & retrieve and I don't want to choke the database connections retrieving images.